# Independent events in "coin tossing space"

Tags: measure-theory

This question really puzzles me.
The setup:

We define the "coin tossing space" by starting with the set $\Omega = \{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb N}$ and then defining the finitely determined events $t \in \Omega$ as the events $E \subset \{ 0,1 \}^n$ such that $\pi_n^{-1}(E) = \{ t \in \Omega : (t_1, \ldots, t_n) \in E \}$ where $\pi_n : \Omega \to \{ 0,1 \}^n$ is the projection of the first $n$ elements of $t \in \Omega$. That is, we can write the finitely determined elements of $\Omega$ as:
\begin{equation}
\mathscr A_n = \{ \pi_E^{-1}(E) : E \subset \{ 0,1 \}^n \}
\end{equation}
We now set $\mathscr C = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} \mathscr A_n$ which is an algebra and define on this the function $\iota$ by $\iota \left( \pi_E^{-1}(E) \right) = \mu_n(E)$. Since this is a probability space one can extend this uniquely to a complete measure space $(\Omega, \mathscr A, \mu)$ called the coin tossing space, where $\mathscr A = \sigma(\mathscr C)$ and $\mu_{|\mathscr C } = \iota$ using the outer measure approach.

The first question is to show that any measurable set in the coin tossing space can be approximated by finitely determined events. This is fine.

For the next question we define a new projection $\pi_K : \Omega \to \{0,1\}^K$ where $K \subset \mathbb N$ is a finite set and the mapping is given by $\pi_K(t) = (t_k)_{k \in K}$, i.e. the set $K$ gives the indices of which the projection "saves". Now let $K,L \subset \mathbb N$ be two finite sets, $A \subset \{ 0,1 \}^K, B \subset \{ 0,1 \}^L$ with $A \cap B = \emptyset$. I am asked to show that then $\pi_K^{-1}(A)$ and $\pi_L^{-1}(B)$ is independent, i.e 
\begin{equation}
\mu \left(\pi_K^{-1}(A) \cap \pi_L^{-1}(B) \right) = \mu \left( \pi_K^{-1}(A) \right) \cdot \mu \left( \pi_L^{-1}(B) \right).
\end{equation}

I cannot make this make sense. In the case where $K \cap L = \emptyset$ it is easy to see that it must be true, but if the events may share some index then there is a "loss" of information in the intersection of these events and it seems to be not true. I fear that there is something obvious here that I have missed, but the problems to me seems to be ill-posed.

Comment: My vote goes to a misprint since, as you said, $A\cap B=\varnothing$ makes no sense while $K\cap L=\varnothing$ does.